# Problem with numbering of figures

Tags: tables, floats, numbering

I need to reset numbering of figures and tables to 1, 2, 3 and to get rid of numbering 1.1, 1.2, 1.3,... I tried many commands but nothing worked. Could you help me please?

The `.cls` file is [HERE](http://exdb.fit.cvut.cz/browser/zp/1213-zima/martiada/FITthesis.cls?rev=1217).

Document:

```
\documentclass[thesis=B,czech]{FITthesis}[2012/06/26]

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\department{text}
\title{text}
\authorGN{text}
\authorFN{text}
\authorWithDegrees{text}
\supervisor{text}
\acknowledgements{text}
\abstractCS{text}
\abstractEN{text}
\placeForDeclarationOfAuthenticity{text}
\declarationOfAuthenticityOption{1}
\keywordsCS{text}
\keywordsEN{text}

\begin{document}

\begin{introduction}
    %
\end{introduction}

\chapter {First}

text

\begin{figure}[h]
  \caption{Function.}
  \label{fig:function}
\end{figure}

\begin{conclusion}
    %
\end{conclusion}

\appendix

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand\thetable{\arabic{table}}
```

(the first two lines require the `chngcntr` package), but you need to do these `\AtBeginDocument`:

```
\documentclass[thesis=B,czech]{FITthesis}[2012/06/26]

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\department{text}
\title{text}
\authorGN{text}
\authorFN{text}
\authorWithDegrees{text}
\supervisor{text}
\acknowledgements{text}
\abstractCS{text}
\abstractEN{text}
\placeForDeclarationOfAuthenticity{text}
\declarationOfAuthenticityOption{1}
\keywordsCS{text}
\keywordsEN{text}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
  \counterwithout{table}{chapter}
  \renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{figure}}
  \renewcommand\thetable{\arabic{table}}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{introduction}
    %
\end{introduction}

\chapter {First}

text

\begin{figure}[h]
  \caption{Function.}
  \label{fig:function}
\end{figure}

\chapter {First}

text

\begin{figure}[h]
  \caption{Function.}
  \label{fig:function}
\end{figure}

\begin{conclusion}
    %
\end{conclusion}

\appendix

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! But what about the tables? Concretely numbering by longtable? There is the same problem.

Comment: @goLK It's the same thing but using "table" instead of "figure". Please see my updated answer.

Comment: It's a little bit of off-topic but do you know why the longtables are not shown in `\tableofcontents*`? I use normally `\caption{text}` and `\label{tab:text}`. And what does the `\listoftablescond` do? I am very confused.

Comment: @goLK I did a test with `longtable` and it does appear in the List of Tables. Perhaps you can open a new question with this new issues, providing a MWE there.